# TextView: unable to change text color at runtime

Tags: android, colors, textview

This is my first post here.
I've to change a `TextView's` text color at runtime. There's a method `TextView.setTextColor(int)`, but it doesn't work with int values that are not in resources. 
**For example,** a color calculated at runtime such as `0xFF0000 (RGB)`, not present in `R.color`, doesn't work. The `TextView` is not rendered.
I've taken a look at android source code for this, and there are two methods, none of them accept `rgb int values` as argument:

```
/**
 * Sets the text color for all the states (normal, selected,
 * focused) to be this color.
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_textColor
 */
@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    mTextColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);
    updateTextColors();
}

/**
 * Sets the text color.
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_textColor
 */
public void setTextColor(ColorStateList colors) {
    if (colors == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    mTextColor = colors;
    updateTextColors();
}
```

**So there's no way of doing this? Maybe extending `TextView`?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the question? Text color can be set anywhere in the UI thread by using constants and methods from `android.graphics.Color` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem might be you're not setting the color's alpha value.

`TextView.setTextColor()` does not accept 0xRRGGBB values.  Instead, it accepts `0xAARRGGBB`.  Whenever you put `"0xFF0000"`, you are actually giving the value `"0x00FF0000"` which gives it an alpha value of "0" which is why the `TextView` is not rendered.  Thus, instead of 0xFF0000, try to set it to 0xFFFF0000.

Alternatively, you can use Android's Color class.  The method **"Color.rgb(int, int, int)"** implicitly assigns the alpha value of 255, so calling `"Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)"` should yield a red color value for the text.

Comment: But the [sdk document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColor) says it accepts RGB as well..

Comment: That is for xml attributes.  The method does not.  Simply passing in the value "0xFF0000" into the setTextView(int) method will make the text invisible.

Comment: huh I always thought that both should be the same.. but I have never tried.

Comment: So it works with alpha channel, but where in the source code is that method? The only one with an int argument in TextView class (see above in my post) searches in resources, with this line `mTextColor = ColorStateList.valueOf(color);`

Comment: What method are you talking about?  My previous comment has a typo.  I say "setTextView(int)", but I really meant "setTextColor(int)".  I didn't notice till just now, but it won't let me edit it now.

Comment: If you want to set a red color, the value you want is 0xFFFF0000.  This sets alpha to 255, red to 255, green to 0, and blue to 0.  You can get that value three ways:  Either type "0xFFFF0000" as an int value; put "0xFFFF0000" in color.xml and retrieve it through resource (can use context.getResources().getColor(R.color.red) if you name it "red" in the xml); or use Color.rgb(255, 0, 0).  Color.rgb(255, 0, 0) (or Color.rgb(0xFF, 0, 0)) will return 0xFFFF0000 as the alpha value is implicit.

Comment: @DeeV you are right, the correct sentence using Colors class would be like this: `int color = Color.rgb((textColor & 0x00FF0000) >> 4, (textColor & 0x0000FF00) >> 2, textColor & 0x000000FF)`

Comment: Color.rgb() is merely a convenience method to retrieve an integer value containing the alpha, red, green, and blue values.  The value of each parameter should be 0-255 (or 0x00 to 0xFF).  I'm confused why you would AND and bit-shift anything.  What is "textColor"?  Why do you AND it with those hex values?  Why do you bit shift them?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

take instance of `TextView` and call `setTextColor` method

suppose you have TextView with id myTextView, then first get the instance of it

```
TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
```

then call `setTextColor` method

```
myText .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
```

OR

```
myText .setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(int red,int green,int blue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,0,0));
```